# List of controls to show Html of any complexity in Silverlight3

Tags: html, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Requirements to render properly any html ( CSS , tables and etc...  ) either from url or string  and possibility to intercept click on custom hyperlinks ( looking like usual ones ) and do something else instead  of navigation ( navigation silently suppressed , because url may be a fake , but information from "a" tag - id attribute , fake url -  is used in Silverlight application itself ).

Comment: I need vendor/control name with functionality I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 controls I can think off:
1. David Anson's [HtmlTextBlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2008/03/17/continuing-support-for-simple-html-display-in-silverlight-htmltextblock-sample-updated-for-silverlight-2-beta-1.aspx) - free open source and only formats really basic html.
2. [DevExpress AgRichEdit](http://demos.devexpress.com/AgRichEditDemos/) - 1,000$~, Renders every plain HTML I managed throw at it. I haven't tried CSS, Javascript or embedded flash, but i'm not sure that's needed. Generally, pretty awesome.
3. [C1 RichTextBox](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RichTextBoxSilverlight/) - 800$~, same as DevExpress.
4. [Vectorlight RichTextBlock](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls/rich_textblock.aspx) - 200$~. When I tried testing it for what HTML it supports I managed to break it pretty fast.